# Ending an activity on a background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, thread-safety

I gather that it is bad practice to call `finish()` on an activity from a thread that is not the UI thread. I need to end an activity when a certain event (calculated in a rendering/loop thread) takes place.

According to an answer on a similar question, using a Handler to post a request to finish the activity on the UI thread would be appropriate. I attempted to do this but the activity never ended - is there something I must do before posting it, or is there an entirely different method I should be using?

Comment: Show your Code. and LogCat too if any error occurs..

Comment: I would love to know the reason for the downvote on this perfectly valid question. Someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers by default are created on the (Looper) thread that they are instantiated in.  To ensure that a Handler is on the main UI thread, you can do this:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Then, to post items to the main thread, create a class that implements the `Runnable` interface then post to the Handler.

```
myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     // Code to run on UI thread.
  }
});
```

Another handy dandy trick is you can post to a `View` that's visible of your Activity.  For example your root view.

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
Runnable runnableObject = new MyRunnableObject();
myView.post(runnableObject);
```

Some things to note about this. Everything posted to Views will run on the UI thread. Items posted to `Views` **will not execute until the `View` is on the View tree**. You can post Runnables to your `View`, and then they all fire the second the `View` is visible to the user.  It should also be noted that it's not particularly easy to cancel `Runnable`s that have been posted to Views.  They use a Handler internally, but the `remove____()` methods are abstracted out.